# Looking to convert my bat file to Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have the 2  batch files below that I want to convert into Powershell.

I have bat1.bat associated with a file extension so when I double click on that extension bat1.bat is executed and the first parameter is the filename that was double clicked

Why use 2 bat files?  Well if I just use bat2 I get a command window open and visible until the final program is exited. By using the 2 batch files above I only get a taskbar icon (which I want to get rid of).  Which brings me to why I want to convert to Powershell.  I want to be able to double click on one of the files and have PS open the Access program and have no icon or any visual indication at all.  So it would appear that my Access program is the program that handles files with that extension.

Bat1.bat

```
@echo off
@START /MIN c:\temp\bat2.bat %1
exit
```

Bat2.bat

```
@echo off
"c:\temp\Test.accdb" /cmd %1
exit
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in front of a PC to test this right now, but could you not just associate the file extension to a bat that runs the following?

```
@start "Access wrapper" "c:\temp\Test.accdb" /cmd %1
```

I'm all for switching to PowerShell, but your batch file will be faster initially, and if I recall correctly, you can pass a known file type (like your accdb file) to the "start" command and it will figure out what to open it with (ie. Access) and then continue on to the next line in the script (unless you pass "/wait").  Since there wouldn't be a next line in the script, the script and its window would just go away.

I think you could probably eliminate the batch all together with some creative registry edits, but I'm not at a PC right now to test that and I don't want to have people tinkering with the registry just from untested tidbits in my memory.